# Storing query conditions in db

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two entities: Activity and Rule.

The "activity" has some constant fields (user_id, type, date, etc). And some dynamic fields (payload), which depend on activity type. For example an activity saved when user orders something:

```
{
    user_id: 1,
    date: 2020-01-01,
    type: "user_ordered",
    payload: {
        total: 100,
        items: 2
    }
}
```

The second entity is Rule, which basically defines which activities to track.
For example, there can be an "orders with items = 2" rule or "orders with total > 10 and date > 2020-01-01".

The problem is I can't decide how to store and query such cases.
It's possible to store activity payload as json, but how to store these conditions like "total > 10" or "items = 2" and use them to select activities?
Maybe I should look more towards nosql db's?

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: For example, formalize and enumerate conditions. Then check a record against conditions by their formalized numbers, like `WHERE (condition_number = 1 AND total > 10) [OR | AND] (condition_number = 2 AND items = 2)` ... or use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to represent all conditions you need with min/max values. E.g. `total > 10` could be expressed by `min_value = 11, max_value = null`.

The realtional tables would involve key/value tables for the details that are different for each type.

### Table activity

```
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+
| activity_id | type         | user_id | date       |
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+
|           1 | user_ordered |       1 | 2020-01-01 |
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+
```

### Table activity_detail

```
+ ------------+-------+-------+
| activity_id | key   | value |
+ ------------+-------+-------+
|           1 | total |   100 |
|           1 | items |     2 |
+ ------------+-------+-------+
```

### Table rule

```
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+
| rule_id | type         | user_id  | min_date   | max_date   |
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+
|       1 | user_ordered |          | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 |
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

### Table rule_detail

```
+ --------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| rule_id | key   | min_value | max_value |
+ --------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | total |        11 |           |
|       1 | items |         2 |         2 |
+ --------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

### Query

```
select a.*
from rule r
join activity a on a.type = r.type
               and (a.user_id >= r.min_user_id or r.min_user_id is null)
               and (a.date >= r.min_date or r.min_date is null)
               and (a.date <= r.max_date or r.max_date is null)
where r.rule_id = 1
and not exists
(
  select
  from rule_detail rd
  join activity_detail ad on ad.key = rd.key
  where rd.rule_id = r.rule_id
  and ad.activity_id = a.activity_id
  and not
  (
    (ad.value >= rd.min_value or rd.min_value is null)
    and
    (ad.value <= rd.max_value or rd.max_value is null)
  )
);
```

The alternative would be flat tables where you make room for all possible attributes:

### Table activity

```
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| activity_id | type         | user_id | date       | total      | items      | name       | location   |
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|           1 | user_ordered |       1 | 2020-01-01 |        100 |          2 |            |            |
+ ------------+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

### Table rule

```
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| rule_id | type         | user_id  | min_date   | max_date   | min_total  | max_total  | min_items  | max_items  | min_name   | max_name   | min_location | max_location |
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|       1 | user_ordered |          | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 |         11 |            |          2 |          2 |            |            |              |              |
+ --------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

### Query

```
select a.*
from rule r
join activity a on a.type = r.type
               and (a.user_id >= r.min_user_id or r.min_user_id is null)
               and (a.date >= r.min_date or r.min_date is null)
               and (a.date <= r.max_date or r.max_date is null)
               and (a.total >= r.min_total or r.min_total is null)
               and (a.total <= r.max_total or r.max_total is null)
               and (a.items >= r.min_items or r.min_items is null)
               and (a.items <= r.max_items or r.max_items is null)
               and (a.name >= r.min_name or r.min_name is null)
               and (a.name <= r.max_name or r.max_name is null)
               and (a.location >= r.min_location or r.min_location is null)
               and (a.location <= r.max_location or r.max_location is null)
where r.rule_id = 1;
```